# Trying differents look & feel Views on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm developing a dashboard with lot of objects, I did 2 versions of the View "Index.cshtml" and "Index2.cshtml", I tried each one renaming them. Can I expose both using the same Index controller (one action)? Like:

```
www.blabla.com   www.blabla.com/Index2
```

Using routes maybe?

Comment: You want to have two layouts for one view?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC allows you to show a single view. What you can do it to create a partial view an include it on your view.

Comment: 2 views from one controller, yes each one with different content, for testing purpose

Comment: Use condition statement in action methods to render view

Comment: Since you have two actions, it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself badly, I have one action, I only changed the view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just select which view you're going to render in your action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

So you can put that in a variable and change it all the way you like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string viewName = "Index";
    return View(viewName);
}
```

For example by adding a "layout" query string parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(string layout = null)
{
    string viewName = "Index";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(layout))
    {
        viewName = (layout == "2") ? "Index2" : viewName;
    }

    return View(viewName);
}
```